# Proof verification: $[0,1]^\omega$ in the uniform topology is not limit point compact.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

We wish to find a subset $A\subset[0,1]^\omega$ that is infinite and has no limit point. This will prove that $[0,1]^\omega$ is not limit point compact.

My attempt:

Let $A$ be the set of binary strings. Let $x \in [0,1]^\omega-A$. Now for any $a \in A$, the uniform distance between $a$ and $x$ will not be $0$, as $x_i\notin \{0,1\}$ for some $i$. Indeed the uniform distance $\overline{p}(a,x)$ will be either $|x_i|$ or $|1-x_j|$ or $1$, for some $i,j$ where $x_i,x_j\notin \{0,1\}$. If we take $r < \min\{|x_i|,|1-x_j|,1\}$, then $B_\overline{p}(x,r)$ does not intersect $A$ at any point.

Is my approach correct? This is not a finished proof, just the idea I'm working on. However, I'd like to know if this is at least in the right direction. If not, a nudge in the right direction is enough; no need for complete answers.

A few thoughts I have

1. Should $r$ rather be taken as $r<\overline{p}(x,A)$? Wouldn't this guarantee that no $a \in A$ is an element of the ball $B_\overline{p}(x,r)$?
2. My formulation of $r$ might be lacking; I feel there is an example sequence that will invalidate the approach. However, I have been unable to come up with one. Perhaps a decreasing sequence of rationals?
3. Binary sequences might not work, but I feel at least a subset of these has to work. $$A=\{x_i=\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{i-1},1,0,\dots\}$$ for example should work based on my idea (uniform distance is either $0$, $1$, or $x_j\in(0,1)$ so we take small enough $r$ to not contain any other point besides $x$. How to formulate this $r$ rigorously?).

Comment: If $X$ is a  metrizable space (a space whose topology can be generated by a metric) then ($X$ is not compact) iff ($X$ is not  limit-point compact) iff ($X$ has an infinite closed discrete subspace $Y$)..... (I.e. $Y$ is an infinite closed sub$set$ of $X$ and $Y$ is a discrete sub$space$ of $X$)... This does not hold for all spaces. E.g. the $\in$-order topology on $\omega_1$ is not compact but it is limit-point compact and has no infinite closed discrete subspaces.

Comment: Your first idea was fine. If $p$ is a metric on $X$ and $A\subset X$ such that $\inf \{p(x,y):x,y \in A \land x\ne y\}>0$ then $A$ is a closed discrete subspace of $X.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when we have two distinct sequences $x=(x_n), y=(y_n)$ with values in $\{0,1\}$ only, then there is a coordinate $k$ where they differ and thus $\bar{p}(x,y) \ge |x_k - y_k|=|0-1| = 1$.

If $z$ would be a limit point of $A$ (the set of all binary sequences), then $B(z,\frac13)$ (or any other radius) would have to contain infinitely many points of $A$ (as is the case in any metric space) and this cannot be as the diameter of that ball is $<1$. QED.

Comment: This is somewhat what I was aiming for. Thanks for the formalization! Do you have any comments on my proof attempt?

Comment: @hampster the $r$ you chose works fine for $x \notin A$. For $x\in A$ you needs more refined argument as I gave.